window.solana.signTransaction breaks partially signed transactions
I am trying to partially sign transactions on the front-end. If I sign transactions using a keypair with transaction.partialSign, there is no problem. But if I sign it with window.solana.signTransaction, the transaction is deconstructed and I can't validate it in the back-end
Notes:

the transaction I'm trying to sign has no previous signature

I have no idea how to solve this problem
